# Is there a library for single producer multiple consumers channel?

Tags: rust

The channel for multiple producers and single consumer is in the rust standard library: [std::sync::mpsc - Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/index.html)

Is there a library for single producer multiple consumers channel somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: you should always first search on crates.io when you are looking for a library https://crates.io/crates/chan

Comment: There's also https://github.com/mahkoh/comm

Comment: https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam-channel

Answer (score 2):

I found [viperscape/oyashio](https://github.com/viperscape/oyashio) in reddit threads below:

- [Rust Pipelining Patterns : rust](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/39hg6p/rust_pipelining_patterns/)
- [First steps for a pipeline model in Rust : rust](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/39toz3/first_steps_for_a_pipeline_model_in_rust/)